# Firefox includes border in height of <hr> whilst chrome does not

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to style a border so that it consist of a

1px green line below a 1px white line

```
hr{
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #89a889;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
}
```

this works in webkit, but firefox seems to include the border in the total height of the line. This makes the bottom border cover the green line. Whan can I do about this?

Answer (score 2):

```
hr {
    height: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #89a889;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fafafa;
}
```

Use two borders.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eCaxz/)

Alternatively, if you really want it to work with a background color, use `box-sizing: content-box` to get Firefox to display an `hr` with the normal CSS box model.

You may want to include other vendor prefixes.

```
hr {
    height: 1px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eCaxz/1/)

Comment: I added another solution if you want to use `background-color`, though I'd recommend using borders.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `-moz-box-sizing: content-box; box-sizing: content-box;`.  The UA stylesheet sets it to border-box sizing.