# Why set box-sizing: content-box; on a singular element?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was just going through the bootstrap.css file and came across the following lines of code :

```
hr {
  -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
          box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
```

I have one single question and one question only, why the explicit `box-sizing: content-box;` when the entire document has its `box-sizing: box-border;`? Why would you switch one singular element to `box-sizing: content-box;` ?

The example I have provided is only one instance of the box-sizing of an element being set to `box-sizing: content-box;`, I have seen this being done a lot of times in CSS style sheets and fail to ever seen the practicality of such styling.

Why might adding a `box-sizing: content-box;` to a singular element be useful? Would someone provide a practical example ?

Comment: setting it to content-box resets it to the css default, if I knew why, then I'd be answering rather than commenting ...

Comment: @ToniLeigh , Thanks , i know that but setting `box-sizing: content-box;` on a singular element seems to be a big deal , because i see such explicit declarations more and more , but i have very little insight into why such a thing is done. I am not a CSS expert , i am sure somebody can come alot and answer, and provide a good example too .

Comment: it's certainly a common pattern to set a default then over-ride that; css has some funny defaults and one of them is box-sixing - it should be border-box to make calculating sizes easier, that's why you'll often see `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` in boiler plate and resets. As for why, I really don't know why content-box would be preferred on an `<hr>`

Comment: This example explains why bootstrap normalised box-sizing for `hr`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219709/firefox-includes-border-in-height-of-hr-whilst-chrome-does-not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at the [Bootstrap source Less files](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/tree/master/less), we see that these lines of CSS actually comes from the [normalize.css project](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/). The goal of normalize.css is to create a consistent CSS base across browsers. I found [a commit](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/commit/fdb11ae5b5e63431d6f8bd2496a11c08e9de46c5) from a few years ago where this CSS was added. The explanation for that commit states:

> Firefox uses different `box-sizing` and `height` values to all other
>   browsers. Firefox doesn't currently support `box-sizing` without the
>   `-moz-` prefix, so we use both the vendor-prefixed and unprefixed
>   properties to ensure that it matches the `content-box` value of other
>   browsers. It also requires the `height` to be set to `0`.

That commit then links to [issue #133](https://github.com/necolas/normalize.css/pull/133) which states:

> The box-sizing of the HR element is set to border-box in latest
>   Firefox (15) while it is set to content-box in Chrome (22), Opera
>   (12), Safari (5.1), IE9 and IE8.

So, it sounds like this was introduced to explicitly make the `box-sizing` of the `hr` element consistent across browsers. In the context of the Bootstrap project, this is probably unnecessary since Bootstrap is already providing consistency by setting all elements to `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: Fantastic ! , did't think it was because of browser inconsistency , but ur answer explains it well .

Comment: just out of curiosity , what did you search for to find out all this ? :)

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik I searched for the css `hr {` in the Bootstrap repo first, which lead me to their normalize.less file. From there it was easy to look through the commit history of the normalize project to figure out when they added that css.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sir :)

Answer (score 4):

The content-box setting makes more sense when you consider that it is paired with height:0. If an element had height:0 and box-sizing:border-box, that would mean that the hr had to have zero height, even including borders. In other words, it would be invisible. Content-box, on the other hand, means that the border is not counted as part of the height, so a border can still be visible even with height 0.

Styling hr elements is notoriously inconsistent across browsers, and they apparently decided to normalize the height to 0 to eliminate some inconsistency. By extension, that probably also means that they intended hr elements to be styled with the border property. Granted, that decision by itself strikes me as a bit odd since I thought that Opera didn't respect borders on hr very well. So while I'm not sure it makes *perfect* sense to me either, it's not every bit as strange as it might look at first.

Answer (score 2):

That code you referenced in bootstrap actually comes from Normalize.css https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/:

```
/**
 * Address differences between Firefox and other browsers.
 */

hr {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  height: 0;
}
```

The documentation is limited to, "Address differences between Firefox and other browsers." That said, `box-sizing: border-box` forces the height and width values to include both padding and **border**. Firefox uses borders to render the line you see when using the hr tag. If `box-sizing: border-box;` and `height: 0;` are used in conjunction you would see nothing in FF, unlike other browsers.

Comment: I ran a test in current versions of FF, IE, Chrome, and Safari and did not see a difference between the rendering using border-box so this may have been to support previous version of FF.